# How I can edit the grid view using the server side

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, data-binding, gridview, datasource

I am using the grid view to display a particuler columns after the search. The program force the user to choose one of the options in the dropdownlist. My server side is this

```
    string searchText = TextBox.Text.Trim();
    int index = DropDownList.SelectedIndex;

    CustomersTableAdapter cta = new CustomersTableAdapter();

    if (index == 0)
    {
        gvResults.DataSource = cta.GetCustomerByFirstName(searchText);
        gvResults.DataBind();
    }
    else if (index == 1)
    {
        gvResults.DataSource = cta.GetCustomerByLastName(searchText);
        gvResults.DataBind();
    }
```

This way the program display all the columns. But I need to delete some columns. I am not allowed to touch the client side because the drop down list won't be able to work.

I am using table adapter which bring the data needed from my database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I knew the answer. You should first put the `AutoGenerateColumns="False"` in the client side. And then add the boundfiels manually. After that, you should write `gvResults.Columns[0].Visible = false;` in the server side.

Thanx

Answer (score 1):

You can hide certain columns depending on what you need.

```
gvResults.Columns[0].Visible = false; //hides the first column of the gridview
```

You can decide which columns to hide depending on the dropdownlist selection.

Comment: it gives me this error ! Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index

Comment: @7alhashmi at what point do you use this code? could you show your code? please edit your question to include your usage of this code.